# Play video from a memory stream inside a xamarin iOS app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am building a app in xamarin that users will use for playing movies. I need the app to play the movie from a memory stream and not from a url or file directly.
Is there a player control or library that i can use to play the movie from a mmemory stream?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no API you can use, what you can do is stream your in-memory representation of the media file at a url.

Use the HttpListener class to create an HTTP server embedded in your application, have it listen say on port 9000, and then have the movie player use an NSUrl like this:

```
new NSUrl ("http://127.0.0.1:9000/myfile.mov")
```

Comment: How secure do you think this is? I mean, isn't it possible for someone to use a fiddler like tool to intercept the response from the url and make a copy of it

Comment: Miguel, can you point me to a working example? We are trying to implement this and the player is not loading the video.

Answer (score 1):

Generally its best to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` ([doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009269)) for playing videos on iOS. Sadly it requires an `NSUrl` to play the video.

What you'll have to do in order to use it, is save your stream to a temporary file.

Such as:

```
string path = Path.GetTempFilename();
using (var yourStream = GetYourStream())
using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
{
    await yourStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

var controller = new MPMoviePlayerViewController(NSUrl.FromFilename(path));
//show the controller
```

Not quite ideal, but it should work.

Comment: im new to xamarin and trying your approach, but what should the GetYourStream() method return?
f.e. i want to access an url like "http://....../stream.m3u", i guess thats what i would have to return there?

Comment: If you have a working url, just use it. `MPMoviePlayerController` and `NSUrl` can take your url and play the movie. The person asking the question had a `MemoryStream` and that was their problem.

Comment: Yeah i found that out later, but the problem i have is a LiveStream which i have to somehow Buffer, then Play.

F.e. Download 1024kb and Start to play that Stream, as its a continous Stream.

When i start that m3u Link in my Browser, it starts Downloading until i stop it. Do you have an Idea how i could achieve this?